# Automatically Enable Submit button at particular time from server using PHP JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What I'm looking for is this.
I have a simple PHP page with a **submit** button that is disabled by default.
I want the submit button to be enabled at a particular time for example 02:00:00

With PHP i can get the time from server with     `date("h:i:s")` which i am using in a JS variable.
 like 
    `var time = "<? php echo date("h:i:s") ; ?>" ;`

Now by using     **setInterval()** method every millisec i am trying to compare the value of "time" variable with the 
particular time i want the button to be enabled. 
like     `if(time=="02:00:00")
{
button.disabled=false;
}`

But the problem is "time" variable should also dynamically change to meet the conditions otherwise nothing will happen.I can't get any simple solution.Do i require AJAX for this?

Any help will be appreciated :) 
Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I would update the `time` variable using JavaScript:

```
var curTime = new Date();
var firstColon = curTime.toString().indexOf(":");
time = curTime.toString().substring(firstColon-2, firstColon+6)
```

I'm a Python person, but I think PHP servers work similarly in that when going to a link, a GET request is sent, and then data is sent back, possibly a dynamically created webpage with Python code, but that webpage can't contain any Python or PHP. Those languages are strictly server-side. You could send a request to the server to get the time, but that would be really inefficient and it's better to do this client side then constantly dynamically change the webpage with requests to your PHP server.

Since this is about disabling a button, if the button sends a request to the server, remember to check that the time is right server-side just in case someone tampered with the webpage using their JavaScript console client-side.

Comment: Just remember that if the button is disabled by security/important reasons, instead of just for a more friendly user interface, you need to check the time on the server when you submit the form too!

Comment: Yes, if there's something about form restriction or validation, there should always be both client-side checking for user interface and server-side checking for security purposes. Thanks for the reminder! I updated my post. @fhelwanger

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this enable/disable done better at server side? Why do you need to enable the submit button in JavaScript at all? Will it be too bad of a solution to simply inform the user that they cannot submit operation is not available at the moment? They can always refresh the page or come back later to see if it is enabled.

Alternatively, you can simply have an ajax request that periodically pings the server to see if the button can be enabled or not. But know that a savvy user can use Web Inspector tools available in modern browsers to change DOM state. Always validate your operations at the server side. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think he needs to do the both. Check it on server-side for security reasons and disable the button/warn the user for a better experience (but do the last without any Ajax please, all you need for that is JS).

Comment: Agreed. On further thought it is a good idea and better UX to do this both client side and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
/* ########## HTML file ######### */
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="timer_function();">
<button type="submit" id="validateIt" style="none">Submit</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxFunction() 
{
var httpxml;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
          try
                    {
                 httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
            catch (e)
                    {
                try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
                catch (e)
            {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
            }
  }
function stateck() 
    {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {
//document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
//document.getElementById("msg").style.background='#f1f1f1';
      }
     if(httpxml.responseText == "02:00:00")
      {
        document.getElementById('validateIt').style.display = 'block';
      }
     if(httpxml.responseText >= "00:00:00" && httpxml.responseText < "02:00:00"
      || httpxml.responseText >= "02:05:00" && httpxml.responseText < "02:00:00")
      {
        document.getElementById('validateIt').style.display = 'none';
      }

    }
    var url="server-clock-ckk.php";
url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
tt=timer_function();
  } 
function timer_function(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('AjaxFunction();',refresh)
}  // Display server time ends
</script>
</html>
/* ########## PHP file server-clock-ckk.php ######### */ 
<?Php
echo date("H:i:s", time());
?>
```